# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) quit automatically after installing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I get this error:

> The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage package did not load correctly.The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension....

when I try to start SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) after installing Visual Studio 2017.

SSMS quits after I click 'Yes'. SSMS quits automatically when I try to restart it.

- Visual Studio version: Visual Studio 2017
- SSMS version: SQL Server Management Studio 17
- Operation version: Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried (re-)installing the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) from the independent download?

Comment: Try turning off "Use hardware graphics acceleration" in options in visual studio and/or ssms (by modifing the config file)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS 17 is using VS 2015 editor engine, looks like some sequence of apps installation/un-installation causes VS 2015 editor corruption.

What helped me is to uninstall SSMS, uninstall "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 Language Support", uninstall (via Modify) "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015", uninstall (via Modify) "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)". Then reinstall SSMS.

Also I've seen posts that SSMS user settings corruption can cause that issue, the easiest way to check that is to create a new windows account and see if SSMS can be started from it. Wasn't my case though.